# Add a class when scrolled to the element

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to add a class to the element, when it's in view a.k.a scrolled to, but I have no clue where to start.

Let's say I want to add it to `<div></div>` block and when it's scrolled in to it, the class will be added and when it's scrolled out of it, the class will be removed.

I would provide some html mark up to apply it on, but I think demonstration on `<div></div>` tags is satisfactionaly to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ui-scroll](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scrollpoint) module adds a class when you scroll past an item. You could fork it and adjust to your needs.

---

You might already know; there are also many jQuery plugins for this and it's pretty easy to wrap this kind of plugin with a directive:

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .directive('onScrollAddClass', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elm, attr) {

        init(elm, attr.onScrollAddClass);

        function init(elm, cls) {
          elm.viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: cls,
            repeat: true
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Here's [the demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoewjB) for above code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way on one of my websites.

```
angular.module("Directives")

.directive("rjOnScrollTo", [
"scroll", "$window", "$rootScope",
function(scroll, $window, $rootScope) {
  function link($scope, $element) {
    var offset = 100;
    var pageLoaded = false;
    var uniqueId = "rjOnScrollTo_" + $element.get(0).id;

    var onScroll = function() {
      if (pageLoaded && $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() - offset >= $element.offset().top) {
        $element.addClass($scope.className);
        scroll.removeCallback($window, uniqueId);
      }
    };

    scroll.addCallback($window, uniqueId, onScroll);

    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
      scroll.removeCallback($window, uniqueId);
    });

    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function() {
      pageLoaded = false;
    });

    $scope.$on("pageLoaded", function() {
      pageLoaded = true;
      onScroll();
    });
  }

  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      "className": "@rjOnScrollTo"
    }
  };
}]);
```

Use like so:

```
<div data-rj-on-scroll-to="my-class"></div>
```

Edit:

You might want to pass the offset parameter in rather than hard-code it.

The service that loads the data from the back-end via AJAX fires the "pageLoaded" event. It was important in my case to wait for the page content to be fully loaded otherwise the div would be immediately in view and the class would be added straight away.

Comment: I've created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/DominikK/pen/QyYRZo) demonstrating your answer. When scrolled to the element I don't see a class added on. Also the console shows `Error: [$injector:unpr]`.